# Cannot access standalone-chrome selenium server via Kubernetes service

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, kubernetes

I have a k0s Kubernetes cluster on a single node.  I am trying to run a `selenium/standalone-chrome` to create a remote Selenium node. The trouble that I am having is that it responds if I port forward `4444` from the pod, but cannot seem to access it via a Service port. I get connection refused. I don't know if it's because it's ignore connections that non-localhost.

The `Pod` definition for `pod/standalone-chrome` is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: standalone-chrome
spec:
  containers:
  - name: standalone-chrome
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
    - containerPort: 4444
    env:
    - name: JAVA_OPTS
      value: '-Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps=""'
```

The `Service` definition I have for `service/standalone-chrome-service` is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: standalone-chrome-service
  labels:
    app: standalone-chrome
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 4444
    name: standalone-chrome
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: standalone-chrome
```

This creates the following, along with a `busybox` container I have just for testing connectivity.

```
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/busybox1                 1/1     Running   70         2d22h
pod/standalone-chrome        1/1     Running   0          3m15s

NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          18d
service/standalone-chrome-service   ClusterIP   10.111.12.1     <none>        4444/TCP         3m5s
```

The issue I am having now is that I'm not able to access the remote Selenium service via `standalone-chrome-service`.  I get connection refused.  For example, here is trying to reach it via the `busybox1` container:

```
$ wget http://standalone-chrome-service:4444
Connecting to standalone-chrome-service:4444 (10.111.12.1:4444)
wget: can't connect to remote host (10.111.12.1): Connection refused
```

I am able to port forward from `pod/standalone-chrome` to my host machine using `kubectl port-forward` though and it works OK, which I think confirms a service is successfully running but not accessible via the `Service`:

```
$ kubectl port-forward pod/standalone-chrome 4444:4444 &
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:4444 -> 4444
Forwarding from [::1]:4444 -> 4444
$ wget http://localhost:4444
--2021-11-22 13:37:20--  http://localhost:4444/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:4444... connected.
...
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help in figuring out how to get the Selenium remote server accessible via the `Service`.

---

EDIT: Here is the updated Service definition with `name`...

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: standalone-chrome-service
  labels:
    app: standalone-chrome
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 4444
    name: standalone-chrome
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    name: standalone-chrome
```

Here is the output of describe:

```
Name:              standalone-chrome-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=standalone-chrome
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          name=standalone-chrome
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Families:       <none>
IP:                10.100.179.116
IPs:               10.100.179.116
Port:              standalone-chrome  4444/TCP
TargetPort:        4444/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service's syntax with:

```
  selector:
    app: standalone-chrome
```

is correct, `selector` should be matched by `label`.

> Services match a set of Pods using labels and selectors, a grouping
> primitive that allows logical operation on objects in Kubernetes.
> Labels are key/value pairs attached to objects

See for more details [Using a Service to Expose Your App](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/).

Now you need to add this `label` (which is `app: standalone-chrome`) to your `pod.yaml` metadata:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: standalone-chrome
  labels:
    app: standalone-chrome # this label should match to selector in service
spec:
  containers:
  - name: standalone-chrome
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
    - containerPort: 4444
    env:
    - name: JAVA_OPTS
      value: '-Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps=""'
```

Comment: This was my issue, I didn't have a proper matching label in my pod metadata.  I thought the issue was in my service metadata, but I needed the label matching in my pod as @moonkotte mentioned.